# unable to run delve in eclipse che - could not launch process, operation not permitted

Tags: go, eclipse-che, delve

I am trying to use [delve](https://github.com/derekparker/delve) in Eclipse Che

Running Eclipse Che in docker with

```
--privileged
```

is not helping

```
docker run -it  --privileged --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(pwd):/data eclipse/che start
```

When running `dlv debug main.go` I get `could not launch process: fork/exec /projects/desktop-go-simple/debug: operation not permitted`

Can you run dlv debugger in Eclipse Che

Comment: You are suppose to supply a package name to `debug`. It defaults to the main package if you omit it.

Comment: This may be unrelated, but on install I got this warning `If you get "could not launch process: could not fork/exec", you need to try in a new terminal.`

Comment: Thanks @RayfenWindspear same thing package or not. Did you start the docker container with --privileged.

Comment: Were you able to do that same in a Docker container? Let's take Che out of equation for a while.

Comment: Yes, it works in docker container - make sure that you have the same versions on host and in container.

Answer (score 0):

Adding --privileged adds capabilities to Eclipse Che CLI only.
Instead of that add `CHE_DOCKER_PRIVILEGED=true` line to che.env file inside of Che data directory mounted to `/data`