# Eclipse Che: bash: gdb: command not found

Tags: node.js, go, codenvy, eclipse-che

Che seems promising but is anyone using it or does it work for anyone at all?

Once in a while I try to make Che debugger work with golang or nodejs. I do belive Che is the way for devs using docker, I just need a workflow.

I run Che in docker described here: https://eclipse.org/che/docs/setup/getting-started/index.html#syntax

I am unable to get delve [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987476/unable-to-run-delve-in-eclipse-che-could-not-launch-process-operation-not-per) to work so today I tried gdb.

Just using the go stack(web-go-simple) and edited the debug command:

```
go build -gcflags "-N -l" -o gdb_sandbox main.go

gdb gdb_sandbox
```

It gives `bash: gdb: command not found`

If I edit the run / Debug Configuration it complains about `cannot connect to localhost:8080`. I set the port to 8080 and binary path to:

```
${current.project.path}/web-go-simple/gdb_sandbox
```

I just want to debug go - anyone done this?

I also tried using nodejs: https://eclipse.org/che/docs/ide/debug/#nodejs
This also can not connect.

Comment: That error means that gdb is either not installed, or not in your `PATH`. Have you looked at [Delve](https://github.com/derekparker/delve) at all?

Comment: Thanks, I did look at delve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43987476/unable-to-run-delve-in-eclipse-che-could-not-launch-process-operation-not-per

Answer (score 1):

Correct, neither gdb nor gdbserver are installed in go or nodejs stacks. You can easily build a custom stack using the following recipe:

```
FROM eclipse/node
RUN sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gdb
```

You can also install gdb and gdbserver right in a running workspace, using the same package manager commands. These stacks are based on Ubuntu 16.04